# Как замедлить загрузку страниц с localhost?

Tags: отладка, ajax, javascript, http

Привет, есть приложение использующее асинхронные `ajax` запросы, наблюдаются некие проблемы при медленном коннекте. На данный момент отлаживаю на `WAMP (windows+apache+mysql+php)` и хотелось бы ограничить скорость к `localhost` скажем до `64 — 128kb/s (2G, slow 3G)` ну и пинг поднять, чтобы понять в чем неприятность и скажем так создать «боевые условия».

Дорогие разработчики, подскажите, может есть какой софт или плагин к браузеру чтобы порезать канал `localhost`? Помнится ранее в опере 9.8 был `butterfly` и там что то подобное существовало, но сейчас найти мне это не удалось... да и опера 9.8 морально устарела...

Comment: https://github.com/mininet/mininet

Comment: http://www.dallaway.com/sloppy/

Comment: @eicto, mininet под wamp?

Comment: wininet под vbox, а там уж как хошь роути.

Comment: но, мининет  вроде умеет ping менять, а ничего другое не  умеет...

Comment: @eicto, всегда устраивал WAMP а теперь понял что то одного, то другого не хватает. Я понимаю что это дело вкуса, да и вопрос достаточно «холиварный», что предложите ВЫ (ос, сервер, ide)?

Comment: @Олег Б, это вопрос не холивара, а здравого смысла. По мне так просто нелепо заниматься разработкой серверного ПО в условиях, которые максимально далеки от среды, в которой оно будет работать.

А про IDE вообще непонятно. Стандартный ответ - да хоть блокнот. Какую бы не посоветовали, потом ещё двадцать тыщ раз сменишь, причём бывает что и по кругу...

Comment: про IDE по вкусу и задачам, а OS - linux удобнее в тыщу раз, хотя-бы виртуалке если так-уж сильно на винде сидите. там сразу можно задачу с ограничением траффика штатными средствами решить (tc), а если надо что-то большее (ping, неск роутеров и тд - mininet)

Comment: @eicto, @klopp — безмерно благодарю Вас!

Answer (score 3):

Варианты:

1. [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), только не забудьте настроить его на перехват запросов с localhost (или в браузере прокси для localhost). Включаете *Simulate Modem Speeds* настраиваете в скрипте правила
2. Google Chrome Dev Tools, вкладка Network, Throttling
   [image]